# Simple C code contains ((c = getchar()) != EOF)

Tags: c, getchar

I run the following simple C code.

```
int main()
    {
         int c;
         while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
             {
                  putchar(c);
                  printf("%d\n", c);
             }
         return 0;
     }
```

The output of code when I enter character A as input from keyboard is as follow:

```
>A 
>A65
>
>10
>
```

Why does this code print the number `10` after each inner while loop?

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you're doing when the program is asking for input.

Are you just hitting <kbd>A</kbd>?

No, you're hitting <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, and hitting the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key results in a newline, so your `while` loop is actually doing this:

```
1. Enter loop
2. getchar() waits for input from stdin
2. You enter 'A', hit 'Enter'
3. c is assigned '65' (integral value of 'A')
4. putchar(c) and then printf("%d\n"), so you see 'A65'
5. getchar() immediately gets next character from stdin, which is linefeed
6. c is assigned '10' (integral value of '\n')
7. putchar(c) and printf("%d\n"), so you see a newline followed by 10.
```

You can make your code ignore the linefeeds/non-printable characters if you want (this depends on your locale), using [`isprint`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isprint):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    for(int c; (c = getchar()) != EOF;) {
        if (!isprint(c)) {
            printf("Ignoring character with value %d\n", c);
        } else {
            putchar(c);
            printf("%d\n", c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

And if I run this:

```
root@6f67da78fe9a:~# gcc -o chartest source.c
root@6f67da78fe9a:~# ./chartest
A
A65
Ignoring character with value 10
```